# "Axiom of global choice"

Tags: ct.category-theory, reference-request, set-theory

In some books on category theory (for example, in J.Adámek, H.Herrlich, E.Strecker "Abstract and concrete categories...") the authors use the idea of "big sets" ("conglomerates" or "collections") which can contain classes (as far as I understand, in the Goedel-Bernays sense) as elements, and they formulate the "generalized axiom of choice", where it is stated that the choice function exists (not only for  families or classes of sets, but also) for families of classes (indexed by elements of those "big sets"). This approach allows to prove, in particular, the existence of a skeleton in each category, and some other useful things.

This generalization of the axiom of choice is also mentioned In Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_global_choice
(as the "strong form of the axiom of global choice").

I wonder if there are any texts with the justification of this trick? The references I found (in particular, those mentioned in Wikipedia) give justification only for usual axiom of choice (for families of sets or for classes of sets, but not for "conglomerates of classes"). So actually I can't understand whether, for example, the existence of a skeleton, is true for all categories (in some interpretation of set theory) or for some special ones... Similarly the other corollaries of this "global axiom of choice" look doubtful for me. I would be grateful if anybody could clarify this.

**UPDATE 21.09.2012**

From the comments I see that there is a risk of misunderstanding, so I want to explain that by  **justification** I mean an accurate (rigorous) definition of the new tool together with the analysis of whether it is compatible with the other tools of the theory.

As an illustration, in the case of the usual axiom of choice (I mean its "weak form", in terms of Wikipedia), there are many textbooks (I can recommend E.Mendelson "Introduction to mathematical logic" or J.Kelly "General topology", the appendix), where the fundamental objects of the theory (in this case, the classes) are accurately introduced (here, axiomatically) and the necessary constructions (like functions) are rigorously defined in the theory. This makes possible to give rigorous formulation to the axiom of choice (again, to its "weak form") inside the theory, and moreover, this presentation of a new axiom is followed by a thorough investigation of whether it contradicts to the previous axioms of the theory. Only after receiving the answer that no contradictions can appear (in fact, a more strong thing is true: the new axiom is independent from the others, that was the result by P.Cohen) mathematicians can use this new axiom without worrying that something is wrong here.

So my question is whether there is something similar for the "strong form of the axiom of choice"? Is it possible that nothing lies behind these words? On the contrary, if there is a justification, where can I read about it?

**UPDATE 21.04.2013**

Dear colleagues, from what I learn on this subject in the textbooks which I found, in Wikipedia and here in MO, I deduce that what people call "axiom of global choice" is just the usual axiom of choice (as it is presented in Kelley's book) applied to some special classes of sets arising in consideration of what is called the Grothendieck Universe. It's a puzzle for me

1. why people call this special case "a stronger form of the axiom of choice", and
2. why they don't want to give references, where this construction is accurately introduced.

With the aim to accelerate the clarification of this question, I now nominated for deletion the article in Wikipedia devoted to his topic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Articles_for_deletion/Axiom_of_global_choice. As I wrote there, I don't exclude that the partisans of the idea will rewrite the article in Wikipedia for endowing "global choice" with some mathematical sense, but you should agree that in its present form this article and the other mentionings of "global choice" available for external observers, look indecently vague. I invite all comers to share their opinion here or at the Wikipedia page.

Comment: One way of putting it is this: the axiom of choice for sets is equivalent to the statement that every small category has a skeleton. Since the definition of category is first order, you could consider the axiom: Every model of the category axioms has a skeleton. This is then prior to any choice of ambient set theory. 

Comment: David, but if I consider a classical category, which is defined in a standard way on the base of set theory, like, for example, a category of topological vector spaces, what should I change in the set theory for obtaining the theorem that this category has a skeleton?

Comment: In general you have to use the axiom of choice for classes, a.k.a. the axiom of global choice.

Comment: @Zhen Lin: Do you mean what they call in Wikipedia "strong form of the axiom of global choice"? My question is where can I read about it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "justification" of an axiom? I'd use that phrase to mean the pre-axiomatic intuitive ideas that lead me to regard the statement as a reasonable axiom to include in my theory. For this purpose, it seems to me that whatever intuition leads you to accept the axiom of choice for sets would probably do the same for classes, conglomerates, and whatever higher entities you include in your theory.

Comment: By justification I mean an accurate definition of the new tool together with the analysis of whether it is compatible with the other tools of the theory. For example, when I apply usual axiom of choice (in Wikipedia it is called the "weak form"), I have in mind 1) one of the textbooks, for example the one by J.Kelly "General topology", where (in appendix) the classes are defined (axiomatically) and functions (as a construction of a theory) and the axiom of choice is formulated, and 2) the results of Goedel and Cohen which show that this axiom is independent from the other axioms of the theory.

Comment: Global choice is a consequence of the "limitation of size" principle in both Morse–Kelly and NBG class–set theory. Indeed, Burali-Forti's argument shows that the class of von Neumann ordinals is a proper class, so by limitation of size, it is in bijection with the class of all sets. Voilà, global choice.

Comment: @Zhen Lin: You swallow the most intriguing part of the explanation: how can a class (which is not a set) be an element of someting else?

Comment: I don't know that much about set theory, but I guess to get a workable theory of conglomerates (in ZF+something) we need some large cardinal axiom and then the axiom of choice is simply the usual axiom of choice, applied to very large sets then. And if the most intriguing part is "how can a class (which is not a set) be an element of someting else?", then this has little to do with the axiom of choice.   

Comment: Michael, according to Neumann-Goedel-Bernays, sets are defined exactly as those classes which are elements of other classes. This implies that these "conglomerates" can't be classes, because otherwise we obtain that each conglomerate of classes is actually a conglomerate of sets, and there is no difference between the "strong" and the "weak" forms of the axiom of choice. So conglomerates must be introduced axiomatically: there must be a new axiomatic system, a theory, with conglomerates as objects, and with the results explaining why this theory extends the usual set theory.

Comment: Sergei: The main reason why you're not getting an answer is not necessarily the meaning of "justification" but the meaning of "conglomerate." None of the standard set theories (ZF, NBG, MK) admit those. Some more esoteric theories do (e.g. Ackermann) but since these can be wildly different from each other, you really need to say which one you're using before any kind of serious analysis can be done. If you don't know which one you are using then you can ask a separate question to figure that out first.

Comment: François, I don't understand you. It's not me who writes books about "conglomerates" or articles in Wikipedia about "strong form of global axiom of choice". My question is addressed to people who understands what these words mean. If they will tell me that this is explained in a paper by Ackermann or by somebody else, I would thank them and start to read this paper. How can I explain what theory they have in mind if the only things I know about it is a mentioning in a book (without references) and an article in Wikipedia (with irrelevant references)? 

Comment: Sergei, the paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.1279v2.pdf by Mike Shulman, who is active here, might give you an idea of how different approaches to set-theoretic foundations of category theory work. And the section on foundations in Adámek, Herrlich, and Strecker has references you can consult.

Comment: Michael, look: in his paper Shulman writes about "collections of classes" (see page 13). But he does not define "collections". Do you know where they are defined? He also writes that global choice follows from the fact that the class of all sets can be well-ordered. Do you understand this implication?

Comment: @ moderators: Gentlemen, I received you message, but the person who sent it to me doesn't reply now, so I hope this direct appeal to you can be useful. If you can edit my post, I would agree with any corrections. If you will explain me what exactly must be changed, I will change this. Anyway, it seems to me I understand your corcern (and the relevant component of the correct answer to my question), and I will not be against if you just delete this thread.

Comment: So your question is quite different: you're wondering what the Wikipedia page is actually saying. Why don't you ask that? Or better yet, why don't you ask on the Wikipedia talk page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Axiom_of_global_choice (They explain the proof but not the precise meaning. For most purposes the argument is correct, but I can think of a few interpretations where it is actually incorrect. The author is the best person to ask in that case.)

Comment: François, OK, I asked this in Wikipedia. But what difference you a speaking about? And I don't understand your reproach. I posted this question here because I used to think that colleagues usually help each other: if I can't find a reference in some field I usually ask people whether somebody heard about this, and as a rule people help. I hope this doesn't break rules here.

Comment: Sergei, there are no "conglomerates" in NBG and MK. However, they can be simulated in any one of a dozen different ways. Most of these simulations will make the statement true but there are other ways that will make the statement false. The Wikipedia authors do not make it clear what they mean. Without that information it's very difficult to say anything. As for a justification, there is one on the Wikipedia page in parentheses. All we know about the author's notion of "conglomerate" is that this argument appears to be sound, so their "conglomerates" are rather tame.

Comment: @ François: There is something totally incomprehensible in your civilization: instead of writing "this notion (with the corollaries we need) can be introduced in this system (ZF, or what you are talking about), see this book (or paper)...", you will waste time on hints until exhaustion. As I see it is not enough to ask western people 5 times about references, one must ask and ask to infinity, and step-by-step some interesting facts (like what you write about NBG and MK) will come to light. Or not - this depends on the health of the one who asks questions.

Comment: Indeed, I am also appalled that my civilization still can't answer vague questions about undefined objects.

Comment: Have a look at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/51257/can-zfc-nbg-be-iterated

Comment: François, but you already said some quite precise things about these "undefined" objects: "there are no "conglomerates" in NBG and MK. However, they can be simulated in any one of a dozen different ways". Don't you see the contradiction? There is always a possibility to say that something is vague, especially if you see that he, who asks, is not a specialist in your field, isn't it? Ask me something about topological vector spaces, and I will easily find a justification for myself for not responding: "this is too vague". Everything depends on the will of he, who answers, I would say.

Comment: @ Linasaurus Rex: thank you very much, that is interesting, I am reading it.

Comment: News from Wikipedia concerning this subject: they finally deleted mentioning about "strong form of axiom of global choice". I don't think that this is a best solution, but this removes some questions. François, sorry if what I wrote about civilizations was rude. Of course, my civilazation has much more awful shortcomings, I know them very well. 

Comment: Why is it a stronger form of choice? Note that you don't need any axiom of choice to choose from finite families of sets; but you need the axiom of countable choice to choose from countably infinite families of sets - which is not enough to choose from larger families; and so on. The axiom of choice is enough for choosing from *set* families; and global choice is the jump from set families to class families. If you think about it in terms of universes, then the axiom of choice is only true in one universe, but when you go to another universe you need a stronger assertion to have choice.

Comment: @Asaf: In Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Articles_for_deletion/Axiom_of_global_choice#Axiom_of_global_choice they have just explained me that "axiom of global choice" is exactly what Kelley calls "axiom of choice". It is a great surprise for me that people used to divide this  general result into classes of special statements depending on different "Universes".

Comment: Sergei, working in set theory settings (rather than category theory settings) one has to discern between sets and classes, much like when working in the natural numbers one has to make the distinction between finite sets and infinite sets. If one accepts set theory as a form of foundation on which category theory is constructed then one has to still care about the distinction between sets and classes, and so one still has to worry about global or local choice.

Comment: Asaf, you exaggerate my ignorance. The problem was that instead of writing simply and clearly that "usual choice" is for sets of sets, while "global choice" is for classes of sets, they pretended that there is a "more powerful choice" for "collections of classes" or for "conglomerates of classes" – that was the main puzzle, and finally it turned out to be a hoax. The aim of my initiative in Wikipedia now was to force them to throw away any rudiments of these sermons. And they did it at last. –

Comment: Sorry... :-) I left my mind-reading cap in my other pants!

Comment: doesn't matter!

Answer (score 9):

Here at least is the usual justification for moving from AC for sets to what is normally called the global axiom of choice, which asserts that there is a class well-ordering of the (first-order) universe.

**Theorem.**

1. The global axiom of choice, when added to the ZFC or
   GB+AC axioms of set theory, leads to no new theorems about sets.
   That is, the first-order assertions about sets that are provable
   in GBC are precisely the same as the theorems of ZFC.
2. Furthermore, every model of ZFC can be extended (by forcing) to a
   model of GBC, in which the global axiom of choice is true, while
   adding no new sets (only classes).
3. In particular, the global axiom of choice is safe in the
   sense that it will not cause inconsistency, unless the underlying
   system without the global axiom of choice was already inconsistent.

Proof. Suppose that $M$ is any model of ZFC. Consider the class
partial order $\mathbb{P}$ consisting of all well-orderings in $M$
of any set in $M$, ordered by end-extension. As a forcing notion,
this partial order is $\kappa$-closed for every $\kappa$ in $M$,
since the union of a chain of (end-extending) well-orderings is
still a well-order. If $G\subset\mathbb{P}$ is $M$-generic for
this partial order, then $G$ is, in effect, a well-ordering of all
the sets in $M$. Furthermore, one can prove by the usual forcing
technology that the structure $\langle M,{\in},G\rangle$ satisfies
$\text{ZFC}(G)$, that is, where the predicate $G$ is allowed to
appear in the replacement and other axiom schemes.

Essentially, what we've done is add a global well-ordering of the
universe generically. And since the forcing was closed, no new
sets were added, and so $M[G]$ has the same first-order part as
$M$.

It follows now that GBC is conservative over ZFC for first-order
assertions, since any first-order statement $\sigma$ that is true
in all GBC models will be true in $M[G]$ and therefore also in
$M$, and so $\sigma$ is true in all ZFC models as well. QED

Comment: I am afraid, this is too technical for me. Are you saying that it is possible to extend the Gödel-Bernays theory in such a way that the axiom of choice becomes more powerful, it can be applied to classes?

Comment: No, I am saying that the extension of ZFC to Gödel-Bernays GBC theory, which includes the global axiom of choice (which is the axiom of choice applied to classes), is known to be completely safe and does not create any new theorems that are purely about sets. (Of course, it does create new theorems about classes, since global AC is such a new theorem about classes, that is not provable in GB+AC without the global axiom of choice.) You can find further discussion of this in any graduate text that treats Gödel-Bernays set theory.

Comment: Which text namely?

Comment: Actually, I even can't find this term at all, "global axiom of choice", in textbooks. I used to think that axiom of choice can be applied to classes of sets, I never saw other versions of this trick, so what you write is completely unfamiliar for me.

Comment: Google search turns up numerous instances: https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=global+axiom+choice#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=axiom+global+choice&oq=axiom+global+choice&gs_l=serp.3...8820.13992.0.14726.18.17.1.0.0.7.581.3283.0j12j4j5-1.17.0...0.0...1c.1.9.psy-ab.hnhXPr9dEEw&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45512109,d.dmQ&fp=e2cb296b96349540&biw=1536&bih=813. See http://books.google.com/books?id=7vDATn64DOUC&pg=PA192&dq=global+axiom+choice&hl=en&sa=X&ei=dctzUe-RBOuz0QH_tIDYBg&ved=0CE4Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=global%20axiom%20choice&f=false

Comment: Also http://books.google.com/books?id=LSsbBU9FesQC&pg=PA185&dq=global+axiom+choice&hl=en&sa=X&ei=dctzUe-RBOuz0QH_tIDYBg&ved=0CEAQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=global%20axiom%20choice&f=false, http://books.google.com/books?id=ah2bwOwc06MC&pg=PA133&dq=global+axiom+choice&hl=en&sa=X&ei=dctzUe-RBOuz0QH_tIDYBg&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=global%20axiom%20choice&f=false, http://books.google.com/books?id=ah2bwOwc06MC&pg=PA133&dq=global+axiom+choice&hl=en&sa=X&ei=dctzUe-RBOuz0QH_tIDYBg&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=global%20axiom%20choice&f=false

Comment: I might add that this is completely standard material when considering Goedel-Bernays set theory, and so if you do find this "completely unfamiliar", then it may be appropriate for you to adopt a less strident tone.

Comment: In particular, the Wikipedia page on global choice http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_global_choice seems to me currently to be completely fine, presenting the standard and familiar facts about it as they are usually understood, including the conservation result that I prove above. Please do not delete that Wikipedia page, and please remove your request for deletion.

Comment: Joel, when making impression of this topic I followed the references of the article in Wikipedia devoted to this "Axiom of global choice". That was before 21/04/2013 when I initiated that investigation on whether this term indeed has sense. There were only two textbooks there, namely, By Jech and by Kelley. None of them contains this term "global choice". My idea was that when people explain something mathematical it is their duty to provide the reader the necessary references, it's not the reader who must catch their hints. 

Comment: The more so that even specialists can't explain some details in those hints. For example, I would be very grateful to you, if you could add  also some references where the term which attracted me from the very beginning is explained -- the "conglomerates of classes". It was mentioned in the Wikipedia article 7 months ago when I created this thread, and for me, an external observer, the impression was that it is exactly "global choice" which describes the properties of those "conglomerates". But up to now nobody explained the meaning of this term.

Comment: And, Joel, I don't agree with you that this is completely standard material. I was also studying logic at the university in Moscow, and  I never met the term "global choice". What Fraenkel, Bar-Hillel and  Levy call "global choice" our professors (and the authors of the books we were reading) called just "choice". To say nothing about  "conglomerates of classes". 

Comment: The axiom of choice for classes (i.e. global choice) is known not to be equivalent to the axiom of choice for sets, as one can build a model of Goedel-Bernays set theory that does not satisfy the axiom of choice for classes but does satisfy AC (this is done in a few questions here on MO).  For this reason, I would regard it as a mistake to refer to both axioms as the "axiom of choice".  Indeed, such a terminology would likely cause students to become very confused about the difference between them.

Comment: Meanwhile, in the context of GBC, where it is understood that one has the axiom of choice for classes and not just for sets, then it seems harmless to refer to the axiom as "choice". But one should still keep in mind that this version of choice is stronger than what is called the axiom of choice in the ZFC context. 

Comment: "I would regard it as a mistake to refer to both axioms as the "axiom of choice"" - however, Kelley and many others do this in their texbooks. On reading that article in Wikipedia (the version of 7 months ago) one could think that a great theory was invented, an extension of Gödel-Bernays, something indeed powerful, which allows to operate with "conglomerates of classes"! Who could expect that the explanation of that peal will be so banal - just terminology: we'll just call this special version of choice a "global choice", and everybody is free to think what he wants about "conglomerates"! 

Comment: Well, the forcing arguments show that global choice (choice for classes) is strictly stronger than the axiom of choice (choice for sets). I don't find that to be banal at all; rather, I find it to be a very enlightening piece of mathematics, explaining something fundamental about the set/class distinction. I would suggest that you take a look at it...

Comment: Joel, I understand that the choice for classes is stronger than the choice for sets, there is no need to persuade me. But (logically) this doesn't mean that everybody must use different names for these two axioms. There is some per cent of people (and I belonged to them) who (after reading Kelley) believe that there is just one axiom of choice, the axiom for classes of sets, and the other its formulations (for sets of sets, for countable sets of sets, etc.) are just special cases. For those people it was impossible to understand what was written in that Wikipedia article before 21/04/2013.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should place yourself in ZFC+ existence of strongly innaccessible cardinals.

Then the existence of a strongly inaccessible cardinal provides you a universe as in Borceux's Handbook of Categorical algebra.

Then, what you call sets are elements of the universe, and what you call classes are the subsets of the universe, but they are still sets in the set theoretic sense, so you can apply choice.

**EDIT: clarification**

The problem of category theory is that we want to have the category **Set** of all sets to actually be a category.

Since there is no set which contains all sets, we can't ask a category to have a *set* of objects, or **Set** will no more be a category. That's why in the first place we define the collection of object to be potentially wider than a set: we ask it to be a class.

The point is that you can avoid the difficulty differently, by limiting yourself to a rich enough set of sets, which should contains "everthing that you can be interested in".

This is the concept of a Grothendieck universe, see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+universe or Borceux's Handbook of Categorical algebra for a definition.

Existence of Grothendieck universes turns out to be equivalent to the existence of strongly inaccessible cardinals (here we are in ZFC), and this existence axiom has been studied in set theory (I'm not a specialist of that at all).

So you place yourself in ZFC + existence of strongly inaccessible cardinals, and you take a universe $U$. Call the elements of U the "U-sets" and the subsets of U the "U-classes".

Then, define a category $\mathscr C$ (in the universe $U$) to be a triple $(Obj~ \mathscr C, Mor~ \mathscr C, \circ)$ with $Obj~ \mathscr C \subseteq U$ and $\mathscr C(A,B) \in U$ for all $A,B \in Obj~ \mathscr C$, satisfying the usual axioms of a category.

So now, your U-classes are indeed sets of ZFC (as subsets of the set U), so you can use the axiom of choice in them, without bothering.

I am not sure if it is what you were looking for, but it is what I personally have in mind when I am using the axiom of choice to choose in a collection of objects, in category theory.

Comment: Dimitri, I did not undertand you. Is this written anywhere? If not, can you contact me to explain what you write? (Or explain this here.)

Comment: I hope my edit made the ideas I tried to express clearer.

Comment: Dimitri, is it possible to translate this into the language of the Gödel-Bernays set theory?

Comment: As far as I understand, $U$ must be a set here, is it? If yes, then I don'see any profits. If the "axiom of global choice" is just the usual axiom of choice applied to families of $U$-classes (which are families of sets), then why do people introduce the very term "axiom of global choice", and claim that "the axiom of global choice is a stronger variant of the axiom of choice which applies to proper classes as well as sets" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_global_choice). This is evidently not true in the situation you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Dear Sergei, you might be interested in first reading Bourbaki's *Théorie des ensembles* (at least chapters I--III) and then have a look at section 0 and the appendix of SGA 4.I. This gives a slightly different approach using Hilbert's almighty symbol $\tau$.

Comment: Appendix of SGA? What is it? In which translation is this? English?

Comment: Dear Sergei, I refer to SGA 4, Expose I, Appendix ("Univers" by N. Bourbaki). I do not know of any translation of SGA, so you have to go with the french original.

Comment: Pedantic remark: Hilbert's symbol was actually $\varepsilon$. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon_calculus